# PHP - allow domains, not subdomains

Tags: php, validation, dns

I would appreciate any help that can be provided with this matter.

I am creating a registration form, one field is for the users domain which I will verify is valid with  `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` and that it exists with `dns_check_record`.

However a problem I'm having is that using these two methods will also allow subdomains to be submitted to the form which I don't want.

Does anyone know a way to allow domains but not subdomains?

I've tested the following function, from http://syntax.cwarn23.net/PHP/Strip_URL_to_Domain:

```
function domain($domainb)
{
$bits = explode('/', $domainb);
if ($bits[0]=='http:' || $bits[0]=='https:')
    {
    $domainb= $bits[2];
    } else {
    $domainb= $bits[0];
    }
unset($bits);
$bits = explode('.', $domainb);
$idz=count($bits);
$idz-=3;
if (strlen($bits[($idz+2)])==2) {
$url=$bits[$idz].'.'.$bits[($idz+1)].'.'.$bits[($idz+2)];
} else if (strlen($bits[($idz+2)])==0) {
$url=$bits[($idz)].'.'.$bits[($idz+1)];
} else {
$url=$bits[($idz+1)].'.'.$bits[($idz+2)];
}
return $url;
```

However this isn't perfect as any domains such as www.domain.uk.com will appear as uk.com (I know not a common domain extension).

Does anyone know a method better than the above function?

Comment: You would have to explicitly check for things such as `.co.uk`, `.com.br`, etc.

Comment: You use the word *subdomain* quite loosely. Do you want reject addresses like `john@customers.example.com`?

Comment: Sorry yes I meant wanted to block anything such as that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Micheal Mior, you have to check for *.co.uk*, *.com.br* and many others.

Some browser vendors are maintaining a list of such non-TLD that are effectively TLD: http://publicsuffix.org/. The list is **[quite huge](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1)**.

There is a library [here](http://www.dkim-reputation.org/regdom-libs/) that uses this effective TLD list to implement the function you are looking for (download are [here](http://www.dkim-reputation.org/regdom-lib-downloads/)). (Found via https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Effective_TLD_Service.)

Comment: ... huge and continuously changing. IMHO it looks like a waste of time.

Comment: Yes it seems the list is massive, it looks like I will just have to manually approve each domain. However thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Combine them.

`dns_check_record` will fail on '.co.uk', so you can split your string on the dots, check the domain you get when you combine the last two parts, and if that fails, use a third part too, if any.

You will do a double check for invalid domains, but I assume that won't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't know it would fail with .co.uk.

Answer (score 0):

first you could use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get only the host name: http://www.stackoverflow.com -> $url['host'] = 'www.stackoverflow.com'

Second you could count the amount of points in the hostname: explode() --> count() or [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Has the host more than 1 point a subdomain could be exist.

Now you could use the solution mentioned by GolezTrol or arnaud576875.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is a much better way of getting the hostname than I was using, I will make a note of that function.

Comment: But if it contains only one dot, you could still have have an invalid url. If one just enters `co.uk`, be careful not to allow it as a valid domain. So actually, not mattery how many dots, you will always have to check if it is a valid domain.